# REDDIT Page 3 of reddit json

Tags: php, json, api, reddit

From the Reddit api, it says it is possible to get the json of a page.  I can do this for the front page, but how do I do I get the json for the third page without visiting the second page?

Is it even possible?

I am using php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the last item from the previous page.
Abridged/simplified C# example of getting "new items" pages (code that parses the previous page passes lastItem back to the method that gets the next page):

```
public static string k_baseUrlFormat = "http://www.reddit.com/r/{0}/new/.json?sort=new{1}";
public static string k_moreFormat = "&after={0}";

// [snip]

        string more = "";
        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( lastItem ) )
        {
            more = string.Format( k_moreFormat, lastItem );
        }
        string url = string.Format( k_baseUrlFormat, subreddit, more );
```

lastItem is item id including type ID, that looks like t3_g6a4s.
You can use other parameters for different stuff in the same way as w/standard web requests for pages.